# access 2007 add column using sub query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to add two columns from a new table into my current query results. Something like this:
[image: PIc]

In SQL I would do something like:

> Select A.Clm1 
> ,A.Clm2 
> ,B.Clm3 
> ,(select udf_number from newTable NT
>   where NT.udf_type_id=1 and NT.id=A.id) as NewColumn1 
> ,(select
>   udf_number from newTable NT where NT.udf_type_id=2 and NT.id=A.id) as
>   NewColumn2
>   
>  from TableA A inner join TableB B on A.id=B.id inner join newTable NT
>   on NT.id=A.id

or even using case something like

> Select A.Clm1 
> ,A.Clm2 
> ,B.Clm3
>   
> ,(case when NT.udf_type_id=1 then NT.udf_number) as NewColumn1
> ,(case
>   when NT.udf_type_id=2 then NT.udf_number) as NewColumn2 
> From..... ...

I tried a few things in access, using sub queries in the from or where part. but didn't get any success. My prb is that I am trying to add two columns based on 1 column in the new table. any help in getting this done in Access?

Answer (score 0):

Join `newTable` *twice*.

In SQL, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT A.Clm1, ...
       NT1.udf_number AS NewColumn1, NT2.udf_number AS NewColumn2
  FROM A 
       INNER JOIN newTable NT1 ON A.id = NT1.id
       INNER JOIN newTable NT2 ON A.id = NT2.id
 WHERE NT1.udf_type_id = 1
   AND NT2.udf_type_id = 2
   AND ...
```

So, basically, you pretend to have two different `newTable`s: One has only the type 1 entries, the other one only the type 2 entries. And you join both to `A`.

In the Access query designer, just add the table twice. Access will probably call them `newTable` and `newTable1`, you might want to change that to something more descriptive. Then add `NT1.udf_type_id` and `NT2.udf_type_id` to the list of columns and add the filter values (1 and 2, respectively).

(Note: This will only return records from `A` for which both a type 1 and a type 2 record in newTable exist. If you want to return all of `A` instead, use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN *and* add the type criterion to the join condition.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the sql version. But in Access, how to return/add the udf_number based on the udf_type_id. Your method will get me adding udf_type_id as a column.

Comment: @camelbrush: You add both `udf_type_id`s to filter -- if you don't want to show them in the output, remove the checkbox. *Also* add both `udf_number`s and to the list of columns and give them meaningful names.

Comment: @camelbrush: Oh, and by the way: If you are more comfortable with SQL than with the Access designer, you can switch the designer into SQL view with the toolbar button in the top left-hand corner.

Comment: I do switch the view, its just that for some reason the sql code doesn't work when I paste it in access! it doesn't use t-sql i guess. I am going to try your above method and come back to post if it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid for access97 and above (I guess)

```
Select A.Clm1, A.Clm2, B.Clm3,
NT1.udf_number as NewColumn1,
NT2.udf_number as NewColumn2
from 
TableA A 
inner join TableB B     on A.id=B.id 
left  join newTable NT1 on NT1.id=A.id and NT1.udf_type_id = A.id - A.id + 1
left  join newTable NT2 on NT2.id=A.id and NT2.udf_type_id = A.id - A.id + 2
```

Please observe the tricky part `A.id - A.id + 1` needed by Access
For other RDBMs (or perhaps newer access versions) it can be:

```
Select A.Clm1, A.Clm2, B.Clm3,
NT1.udf_number as NewColumn1,
NT2.udf_number as NewColumn2
from 
TableA A 
inner join TableB B     on A.id=B.id 
left  join newTable NT1 on NT1.id=A.id and NT1.udf_type_id = 1
left  join newTable NT2 on NT2.id=A.id and NT2.udf_type_id = 2
```

Comment: why are we doing the `NT1.udf_type_id = A.id - A.id + 1` ?

Comment: At least access 97 rejects querys that has a missing table on each side of equal sign. if that is true also for access 2007, I don't know. That was a trick I used a lot. In this case or in a normal sintax (the second query) the purpose is to filter the join over the desired constant.